# jquery.mentionsInput not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am using jquery.mentionsInput in my project. The plugin is working fine on desktop but not working on mobile. This is my code. The alert() is to test check the function is working or not.

```
$('textarea.mention').mentionsInput({

    onDataRequest:function (mode, query, callback) {
      alert("To test on mobile"); 
      searchVal = query;

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: rootPath()+"user/tagFriends/"+searchVal,

        success: function(data){
            data = _.filter(data, function(item) { return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > - 1 });
            callback.call(this, data);
        }

        });


    }
  });
```

This is the plugin [link](http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/). The plugin is also not working on mobile.
Thanks in advance. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

In your file jquery.mentionsInput.js you modify your 2 functions onInputBoxInput() and onInputBoxKeyPress() like this

```
function onInputBoxInput(e) {
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {//certain versions of android mobile browser don't trigger           the keypress event.
if(e.keyCode !== KEY.BACKSPACE) {
 var typedValue = String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode); //Takes the    string that represent this CharCode
inputBuffer.push(typedValue); //Push the value pressed into inputBuffer
}
    }
updateValues();
updateMentionsCollection();

var triggerCharIndex = _.lastIndexOf(inputBuffer, settings.triggerChar); //Returns the last match of the triggerChar in the inputBuffer
if (triggerCharIndex > -1) { //If the triggerChar is present in the inputBuffer array
    currentDataQuery = inputBuffer.slice(triggerCharIndex + 1).join(''); //Gets the currentDataQuery
    currentDataQuery = utils.rtrim(currentDataQuery); //Deletes the whitespaces
    _.defer(_.bind(doSearch, this, currentDataQuery)); //Invoking the function doSearch ( Bind the function to this)
}
}

//Takes the keypress event
function onInputBoxKeyPress(e) {
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(!isAndroid) {
    if(e.keyCode !== KEY.BACKSPACE) { //If the key pressed is not the backspace
        var typedValue = String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode); //Takes the string that represent this CharCode
        inputBuffer.push(typedValue); //Push the value pressed into inputBuffer
    }
}
}
```

and in your index.html

add this code at the bottom of the page

```
<script>


var sendBoxElem = $('textarea.mention');
sendBoxElem.bind("input", function(e) {
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
var char = this.value.charCodeAt(this.value.length - 1);
//$scope.data = char;
if(e.keyCode === undefined){
e.keyCode = char;
}
return true;
}
});

</script>
```

Please inform me if that's work

Comment: thank you, but I did it already and I am busy now for another project. If I use it in future I will inform you

Comment: the solution only works if the `@` is at the end of the text. correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Android Chrome bug known for ages:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639

simo9900 answer is correct in general, but not working for me.

Just add this code in the top of jquery.mentionsInput.js onInputBoxInput function:

```
    function onInputBoxInput(e) {
        if( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) {
            e.keyCode = e.target.value.charCodeAt(e.target.selectionStart-1);
            onInputBoxKeyPress(e);
        }
        ...
    }
```